# Refreshing visible text of a TextView in a Fragment without recreating entire Activity?

Tags: android, textview

While developing my App i ran into some issues while "bugfixing"

In my onCreate() method of my MainActivity 1 service and 1 activity are being started.
They collect data (3 strings in the service, 1 string in the other activity) and i use the onAvitivityResult method to do the job. Because i use an activity instead of a single service it seems like a window is popping in and out quickly (Service and Activity both run AsyncTasks) and i dont really like that too much.

I have recoded basically everything to fit everything inside one service and pass the result on to another class that delivers the strings back to the MainActivity. I am using a default preset (swipeViews) and as it is right now the fragment only displays the string i assigned to it, well great, however that string is being updated by my service, yet the textView itself not.

**How do i make my textView ("textView1") refresh and display the new string ("ClassC.datumh") without having to recreate the entire MainActivity?**

This right here is only a snippet of the output method

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView1.setText(ClassC.datumh); //some random string that comes out of the service          
            rootView.invalidate();
            return rootView;
        }
```

earlier on i used to recreate the MainActivity simply, but as mentioned, i dont really like the "popping" effect created by this..

Comment: Is the problem really the `TextView` not updating or the `static` member `ClassC.datumh` not having the correct value, or Activity1 not receiving notice that the value has updated?

Comment: I belive there is no notice for that method/Activity that the value has been updated. EDIT: Even though it would receive the notice and change the value of the textview the textview would not update itself and thus the old string is still being displayed..

Comment: Make an instance variable of TextView and in onActivityResult change the TextView from there. (bring TextView outside of onCreateView)

Comment: nonono you dont understand, i dont have onActivityResult any longer as i rely completely on services now. But still, what do you mean by an instance variable of my textView?

Comment: Is your `Service` sending an `Intent` instead? You can receive an `Intent` as an event.

Comment: my service creates 4 strings and delivers them to another class where they are being split and recreated (whatever). At the end of that class, nothing happens with the strings, other than assigning them their final values. So to answer your question, no i currently dont use intents in my service. I am looking for a way to recreate the TextView in my MainActivity when a certain condition is met..

Its not a problem for me to assign the textview the correct value, its just that even if the correct value is assigned, the textview is still displaying the old one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinitializing the entire ViewPager did the job. It recreated the TextViews just fine and i was able to see the new Values

```
ClassC.mViewPager.setAdapter(MainActivity.mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
```

For this to work in my service that retrieved the Strings i had to make the ViewPager static in another class (ClassC) and thus i can access it at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

onCreateView is only called when the view is created.  You don't want to recreate the TextView, just update its text.

make textView1 an instance variable in the MainActivity.  When the MainActivity receives the string from the Service, have it run

```
textView1.setText(newStringReceivedFromYourService);
```

Comment: it is not my problem to assign a string to my textview. The problem is that after my service finished and my textview got a new value it wont refresh unless the entire fragment gets recreated..

Comment: how is your service returning the strings?  are you sure the MainActivity has received the new strings?  try debugging to confirm that.  you should not recreate the TextView, and setText would immediately update the value.

Comment: yes i am sure. The preset creates 4 fragments i can access by swiping horizontally on the screen and if i run my app and scroll twice to the page on the right on the 4th page the correct string would eventually appear as the service has finished before the actual fragment with the textview was created, thus the new string was assigned. If i then scroll back to the beginning all fragments on the way are being recreated as well it seems and all of them have the correct string!

Comment: Wait, there is no issue assigning new values! Its just that even though the value has been updated the user wont get to see it unless i restart the entire Activity.. thats what i wanted to say..

Comment: Where has your value been updated into?  A variable in MainActivity, or in ClassC.datumh?  If so, call textView1.setText(variableWithUpdatedText) to update the view's text, and the user will see it immediately.  You should not recreate the activity for this.

Comment: This doesnt work for me as the value gets updated, yes, but the view still displays the old one. I probably need to reload the fragment or rewrite the code responsible for the fragments..